# What is the best practice for writing php row in laravel blade file

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I'm working with Youtube api in laravel 5.4, For converting youtube duration I've used inline php in blade file like this :

```
<?php
     $duration = $video['items'][0]['contentDetails']['duration'];
     $duration = str_replace(array("PT","M","S"), array("",":",""), $duration);
?>
{{ $duration }}
```

I know, It messed up with MVC rule, so whats the best way to deal this kind of situation ? Also I checkout extending [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#extending-blade), but could not understand fully !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply create a helper function to format this duration field.

Create a `app/helpers.php` file in your app root and add this method

```
if (! function_exists('format_video_duration')) {
    function format_video_duration($duration)
    {
        return str_replace(array("PT","M","S"), array("",":",""), $duration);
    }
}
```

Load the helper in composer.json afterwards:

```
"autoload": {
        // ..
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
```

then use it in your blade files or wherever you want

```
{{ format_video_duration($video['items'][0]['contentDetails']['duration']) }}
```

You could wrap this videos array in a class to make using it even simpler, you'd have something like

`{{$video[0]->contentDetails()->formatDuration()}}`